# Probability that a cow gets hit if cars that travel along a certain road follow a Poisson Process

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-distribution

I solved the following problem and just want to make sure my answer is correct.

*Cars that travel along a certain road follow a Poisson Process with rate 9 cars/min. If a cow takes 12 seconds to cross the road, what is the probability that the cow gets hit by a car? (asumme that if a car passes while the cow is crossing, it is unable to stop in time and the cow gets hit).*

So I compute

$P(x(\frac{12}{60})>0)=1-P(x(0.2)=0)=1-e^{-9(0.2)}(\frac{(9*0.2)^0}{0!})=1-e^{-1.8}$

Comment: It is a right way of doing it.

Comment: You mean $(9\cdot0.2)^0$, not $9(0.2)^0$ as is written, and you are right to mean it.